# changing a label using a combobox and a button

Tags: c#, winforms

hi im sorta new to doing projects myself but one of my first tasks was to make a btec grade to ucas points converter by allowing the user to select their grade from the combobox and it would show in a label the correlating grade
however i dont know how to get the selected combobox item to change the label for each different grade
i tried using a an if statement but i realised that it comes up with error CS0029

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace btec_to_ucas
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string PPP = "48";
        string MPP = "64";
        string MMP = "80";
        string MMM = "96";
        string MMD = "112";
        string DDM = "128";
        string DDD = "144";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1 = PPP)
            {
                label1.Text = PPP;
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here: `if (comboBox1 = PPP)`. In this case, `comboBox1` is the *whole* combo box object, with its items, selected index, size, etc. That will never be equal to the string "48". You want to look at the value that has been entered. Try `comboBox1.SelectedText`.

See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netcore-3.1